# NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper with Red5

Tags: java, tomcat, jackson, noclassdeffounderror, red5

I have a [Red5](http://www.red5.org/) application. Since Red5 is based on [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), Tomcat gurus can assist.

I have a class in my application that uses [Spring Social](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/) and [Spring Social Facebook](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/) version 1.1.0M3 that initialize stuff in order to prepare some real time statistics of purchases.

I have a bean configuration that initialize that class with parameters. When I start my Red5 and it tries to create my bean, I get the following error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'xpoFacebookPurchaseHandler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader$1.run(TomcatLoader.java:591)
```

How the bean is configured is irrelevant, so I didn't paste it here.

So I get `NoClassDefFoundError` on `com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper`

Now I'm using `maven` so, whenever I add a package it makes sure that it adds all of it's dependencies and what not.

I have included [Jackson Databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/) v. 2.2.2.

If I execute

```
strings jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar | grep -i ObjectMapper.class$com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.class
```

I do see that the class is there and that library is in the lib directory of my project. So what I can't figure out is why when I execute my project I still get `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: Make sure the jackson libraries (jars) are set in your WEB-INF/lib folder when generating the WAR (or deployable) artifact.

Comment: yea i'm restaring red5 for it to render the directories again and i'm making sure the jars are in place but for some reason it still yells about not finding the proper class.

Comment: when I copy these jars to the lib directory of red5 it works fine. at least that! but why it won't load them from the lib directory of my project ?

Comment: how are you deploying your application in red5/tomcat? If you create a war using maven or an editor like eclipse, make sure the created war includes all jars in lib folder. most likely, you are missing jackson jar in the compiled jar/war.

Comment: i'm not missing any jars, because if i'm copying them to the libs directory of red5 it works fine. but if it stays in the libs director of my project it doesn't. for some reason it needs to be loaded from the libs directory of red5 and not my of my project! can't figure out why!

Comment: In my case, I had excluded jackson-annotations from the pom dependencies. Then, I got the same error. Readding them solved the issue.